# React hooks includes() for checking if a value exists in array gives one wrong answer every time

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple phonebook, which should check if the name exists in the "person" array. I used person.map and includes(). Can anyone explain why this code gives one time "false", when the value should be "true", i.e. the name exists in the person array? It does it every time, but only once.

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState([{ name: "John Doe" }]);
  const [newName, setName] = useState("");

  const addName = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const nameObject = { name: newName };

    let mapped = person.map((ele) => ele.name);
    let found = mapped.includes(newName);
    console.log("found it? ", found);
  };
  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={addName}>
      <div>
        name
        <input value={newName} onChange={handleNameChange} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKfYU.png)

Comment: I'd recommend using the `some` array function, which will avoid the double iteration on the event. `found = person.some(p => p.name == newName)`

Comment: Not related to the issue but you don't need to use `map` and `includes` method to search the `person` array; you could do it just using `find` or `findIndex` method.

Comment: If I type `John Doe` into your input box, console prints `found it?  true`. What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: I left out setPerson etc. because it wasn't the problem. The same phenomenon (I can add a name that exists once) happens also when using some and find.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to add item to array and change state you have to use one of this ways:

```
setPerson(person => person.concat(nameObject)) with .concat()
setPerson(person => [...person, nameObject]) with … spread
```

Answer (score 0):

**Person array is always empty. You are never pushing new values in it so of course includes function it will always return false.** (I was using TS, sorry for the example).

```
import { useState } from "react"

const App = () => {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState<any>([{name: 'John Doe'} ])
  const [newName, setName] = useState<any>('')
  
  const addName = (event: any) => {
   event.preventDefault() 
   const nameObject = {name: newName}
  
   let mapped = person.map((ele: any) => ele.name)
   let found = mapped.includes(newName)

   if(found){
     return //
   }
   setPerson([...person, nameObject])
  }
  
  const handleNameChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {  
   setName(event.target.value)
  }
  
  return (    
    <form onSubmit={addName}>
      <div>
        name
        <input 
        value ={newName}
        onChange={handleNameChange} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type='submit'>add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}  

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. When I updated person array and emptied newName, I had one space inside ''. So, the same name had one space at the beginning and was "a different name".

```
if (found) {
  console.log('found the name')      
}
else { 
  console.log('new name')
  setPerson(person.concat(nameObject))    
}
setName(' ')
```